# How to handle apples feedback-service when pushing to devices?

Tags: service, apple-push-notifications, feedback

I am using Apples (enhanced) push notification system for sending pns. Before pushing to all devices (18k), I run the feedback-service and remove the invalid tokens. Then I start pushing to all devices. There may be some device_tokens in my table, which may have become invalid but are not listed by the Feedback Service. The Feedback-Service lists them only after a failed-delivery attempt. (source: [Apples Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)) So do I have to run the Feedback-Service after every single push, or should I try to push all, run the feedback-service and retry from that token which has been listed as invalid (there should then be only one invalid token  - the first invalid one in the table).

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the feedback service will not tell you about invalid tokens, but only about proper devices where your app is no longer installed.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I also noticed that Apple will not drop your connection when pushing to a device which has been reported by the feedback-service. It only drops you when pushing to a wrong device token. Thank you anyway :)